# Setting Up Connection String of Visual Studio Built in SQL file to ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

I added database file to my built in sql server of Visual Studio and i have also connection string of it but i am confuse how to add this connection string into web.config
here is my try to add connection string to code below :

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="myFirstConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source= .\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Ahdus\Desktop\First Task\First Task\MyFirstTask.mdf"; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=TrueproviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I am much confused that how i can add connection string of my visual studio built in database file to web.config.
Please help me as i am new in asp.net and ignore my way of asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your connection string work with the path you've given, it should look somewhat like this:

Visual Studio 2012 (SQL Server 2012):

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="myFirstConnectionString" 
       connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename=&quot;C:\Users\Ahdus\Desktop\First Task\First Task\MyFirstTask.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Visual Studio 2010 (SQL Server 2010):

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="myFirstConnectionString"
       connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=&quot;C:\Users\Ahdus\Desktop\First Task\First Task\MyFirstTask.mdf&quot;;User Instance=true"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

But you should consider moving the database file to the App_Data folder in your project, and then use `AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|MyFirstTask.mdf` instead.

Comment: after setting up according to you i faced this error message
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: @AmmarRaja I have updated the answer, maybe it works better for you now... I'm assuming you are using Visual Studio 2012, is that correct?

Comment: I am using VS2010 an now my code is <add name="myFirstConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|MyFirstTask.mdf&quot;;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
but still error while debugging the code because dataadapeter is null...Please help

Comment: if you have skype please access my machine and provide help
ammar.asjad is my skype name

Comment: @AmmarRaja Then it should work if the MyFirstTask.mdf file is in the App_Data folder of the project where the web.config with the cnnectionstring is.

Comment: it is not working , i have followed your steps and now i faced this error message
The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))

Answer (score 0):

You should place you .mdf in App_Data folder, then you can use this

```
<connectionStrings>

       <add name="myFirstConnectionString" 
              connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|MyFirstTask.mdf;
              User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

</connectionStrings>
```

With `C:\Users\Ahdus\Desktop\First Task\First Task\MyFirstTask.mdf`, if you move your application to another machine, that path might not exist

`|DataDirectory|` maps to your application `App_Data` folder

Comment: some one suggest me to add your database file under Data Connection Folder and i did but facing problem... so you suggest me to remove file from there and place it under App_Data ??

Comment: Data should be stored in App_Data folder as by default it is protected and web users cannot view files in there